# Python 3 array return value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

fellow python programmers.

I have been working on a small tool that will help automate some email distribution for a repeated task.

I'm writing a function that takes a list of items and I'm stripping out the usernames in the email, matching it with a CSV file and finding the email that correlates with that user.

I am successfully getting all of the information that I need, however I'm trying to return the data in an array that is a list with 3 total columns that should look like so
[reference#, user, email,
 reference#, user, email]

Below is the code that I have tried, but it just returns an array full of zeroes.

```
def gu(tids):
    data = [[0 for i in range(len(tids))] for j in range(1)]
    #In each ticket, splice out the username
    for tid in tids:
        #print(tid.Subject)
        su = tid.Body.find("from ") + 5
        eu = tid.Body.find(" has")
        u = tid.Body[su:eu]
        with open('c:\\software\\users_and_emails.csv', "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for k, row in reader:
                if u.lower() == row[0].lower():
                    #print(row)
                    tidSubject = tid.Subject[30:-1]
                    data[k][0] = tidSubject
                    data[k][1] = row[0]
                    data[k][2] = row[1]
    return data
```

For whatever reason this returns an empty array of the appropriate length

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Could someone help me out in understanding why it's not returning the appropriate value?

The below code without storing values in the array prints out the appropriate values.

```
def gu(tids):
    data = [[0 for i in range(len(tids))] for j in range(1)]
    #In each ticket, splice out the username
    for tid in tids:
        #print(tid.Subject)
        su = tid.Body.find("from ") + 5
        eu = tid.Body.find(" has")
        u = tid.Body[su:eu]
        with open('c:\\software\\users_and_emails.csv', "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if u.lower() == row[0].lower():
                    #print(row)
                    tidSubject = tid.Subject[30:-1]
                    #data[i][0] = tidSubject
                    #data[i][1] = row[0]
                    #data[i][2] = row[1]
                    print(tidSubject)
                    print(row[0])
                    print(row[1])
                    #print(i)
        #return data
```

And it returns data similar to this (have to obscure actual returns, sorry)

```
47299
username1
 user1-emailaddress@foo.com
47303
username2
 user2-emailaddress@foo.com
47307
username3
 user3-emailaddress@foo.com
47312
username4
 user4-emailaddress@foo.com
47325
username5
 user5-emailaddress@foo.com
```

Comment: `for k, row in reader:` only works (and unpacks) if the csv file has 2 colums. I'm not sure that it's what you mean.

Comment: because after that `if u.lower() == row[0].lower():` compares with the first letter of `row`... misleading.

Comment: Why you are filling data at line 2?

Comment: After doing some research, I was lead to believe that I needed to construct the dimensions of the array prior to filling it which is what I was doing with that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The csv does have 2 columns, but that's not what I am wanting to base the array on. Basically, I'm needing to grab the items from the csv after matching it, and storing it in a new array along with data provided by the "tids" variable.

Comment: what is `row` supposed to contain?

Comment: I'll edit the question to contain sample data that should be filled. It works as long as I'm not storing the data in an array, I believe I'm encountering index incrementing issues.

Comment: Thank you all for the help guys, you especially Jean, you helped me on my last question as well. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
def gu(tids):
     data = []
    #In each ticket, splice out the username
    for tid in tids:
        #print(tid.Subject)
        su = tid.Body.find("from ") + 5
        eu = tid.Body.find(" has")
        u = tid.Body[su:eu]
        with open('c:\\software\\users_and_emails.csv', "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if u.lower() == row[0].lower():
                    #print(row)
                    tidSubject = tid.Subject[30:-1]
                    subject = tidSubject
                    row0 = row[0]
                    row1 = row[1]
                    data.append([subject, row0, row1])
    return data
```

Comment: This is closer, but it doesn't iterate for each row in the CSV. It stops after the first item in the list.

Comment: @Justin make sure you return the 'data' after the first for loop

Comment: @Justin no problem